# Spring: Xml based Autowiring a list of beans by interface type

Tags: java, spring, list, interface, autowired

With Spring it is possible to inject a list of beans by the interface class like:

```
@Component
public class Service {
  @Autowire
  private List<InterfaceType> implementingBeans;
  ...
}
```

All defined beans that implement this interface will be present in this List.

The annotation based approach is not possible for me, as the Service class is in a module that must not have spring dependencies.

I need to use this mechanism from outside via xml configuration.

```
<bean id="service" class="...Service">
  <property name="implementingBeans">
    ??? tell spring to create a list bean that resolves all beans of the interfaceType.
  </property>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT: Additionally, there are more than one spring applications that use this service. So the best solution would be to handle this szenario completely via xml configuration. I can then copy the xml parts to all spriong applications that need this.

I want to avoid having a kind of initializer bean that gets the service injected and must then be copied to all spring applications.

Kind regards.

Comment: Can it have `javax.inject` dependencies? You can use `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`.

Comment: nice one, that works.
(convert your comment to an answer to get karma ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XML-only solution would simply have you declare a `<bean>` of the "external" type and provide an `autowire` value of `"byType"`.

> Controls whether bean properties are "autowired". This is an
> automagical process in which bean references don't need to be coded
> explicitly in the XML bean definition file, but rather the Spring
> container works out dependencies.
> [...]
>
> 3. "byType" Autowiring if there is exactly one bean of the property type in the container. If there is more than one, a fatal error is
>    raised, and you cannot use byType autowiring for that bean. If there
>    is none, nothing special happens.

The explanation is a little confusing in that we expect multiple `InterfaceType` beans, but the actual field is of type `List` and Spring will be able to dynamically instantiate one and add all the `InterfaceType` beans to it, then inject it.

Your XML would simply look like

```
<bean id="service" class="...Service" autowire="byType">
</bean>
```

---

My original suggested solution made use of SpEL.

In the module that **does** have Spring dependencies, create a DTO

```
@Component(value = "beanDTO")
public class BeanDTO {
    @Autowire
    private List<InterfaceType> implementingBeans;

    public List<InterfaceType> getImplementingBeans() {
        return implementingBeans;
    }
}
```

and then use [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based) to retrieve the value of `implementingBeans` from the `beanDTO` bean.

```
<bean id="service" depends-on="beanDTO" class="...Service">
    <property name="implementingBeans" value="{beanDTO.implementingBeans}" />
</bean>
```

Spring will create the `BeanTDO` bean, inject all the beans that are of type `InterfaceType`. It will then create the `service` bean and set its property from `beanDTO`'s `implementingBeans` property.

---

Following comments on question:

In an effort to be more JSR 330 compliant, Spring has introduced support for Java EE's `javax.inject` package. You can now annotate your injection targets with `@javax.inject.Inject` instead of `@Autowired`. Similarly, you can use `@Named` instead of `@Component`. [The documentation has more details.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations)